# Phase portraits for a degenerate critical point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

[image]

I want to figure out the cases when $\det A=0.$ I know then one or both of the eigen values are zero. Hence there are three corresponding Jordan Canonical Forms. In Exercise 4 of the same section the author asks to establish eight different types of qualitative behavior.

[image]

Any help in figuring this out is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do not delete your question just after an answer was posted. That is rather unfriendly towards the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

Each example will contain the matrix for $x' = A x, \delta$ and $\tau$, solution for $x_1(t), x_2(t)$, statement of stability and phase portrait.

**Cases for $\det A \ne 0$:**

**Saddle Point**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \delta = -1 \lt 0 \implies ~\mbox{Unstable Saddle}$$

The solution for the system is $x_1(t) = c_1e^t, x_2(t) = c_2 e^{-t}$.

[image]

**Stable Node**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \tau = -5 \lt 0, \delta = 4, \tau^2 - 4 \delta \ge 0 \implies ~\mbox{Stable Node}$$

The solution for the system is $x_1(t) = c_1e^{-t}, x_2(t) = c_2 e^{-4t}$.

[image]

**Unstable Node**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \tau = 5 \gt 0, \delta = 4, \tau^2 - 4 \delta \ge 0 \implies ~\mbox{Unstable Node}$$

The solution for the system is $x_1(t) = c_1e^{t}, x_2(t) = c_2 e^{4t}$.

[image]

**Unstable Focus**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \tau = 2 \gt 0, \tau \ne 0, \delta = 5, \tau^2 - 4 \delta \lt 0 \implies ~\mbox{Unstable Focus}$$

The solution for the system is $x_1(t) = e^t(c_1 \cos 2t + c_2 \sin 2t), x_2(t) = e^t(-c_1 \cos 2t + c_2 \sin 2t)$.

[image]

**Stable Focus**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 \\
 -2 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \tau = -2 \lt 0, \tau \ne 0, \delta = 5, \tau^2 - 4 \delta \lt 0 \implies ~\mbox{Stable Focus}$$

The solution for the system is $x_1(t) = e^{-t}(c_1 \cos 2t + c_2 \sin 2t), x_2(t) = e^{-t}(-c_1 \sin 2t + c_2 \cos 2t)$.

[image]

**Center**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \tau = 0, \delta = 2 \gt 0 \implies ~\mbox{Marginally/Neutrally Stable Center}$$

The solution for the system is: $x_1(t) = c_1 \cos t + c_2 \sin t, x_2(t) = -c_1 \sin t + c_2 \cos t$

[image]

**Cases for $\det A = 0$:**

**Case $\lambda \gt 0 = 1$:**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The solution for the system is (you can plot solution curves) $x_1(t) = c_1 e^t, x_2(t) = c_2$. The phase portrait is

[image]

**Case $\lambda \lt 0 = -1$:** Note: we could easily collapse this case with the previous, just look at the direction arrows (that is why the author says eight).

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The solution for the system is (you can plot solution curves) $x_1(t) = c_1 e^{-t}, x_2(t) = c_2$. The phase portrait is

[image]

**Case Linear Solution**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The solution for the system is (you can plot solution curves) $x_1(t) = c_1 + c_2 t, x_2(t) = c_2$. The phase portrait is

[image]

**Case Degenerate: All Zero Matrix:**

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The solution for the system is (you can plot solution curves) $x_1(t) = c_1, x_2(t) = c_2$.

There is no phase portrait for this case because every point is a constant solution, but it is neutrally stable.

**Aside:**

If you want to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors, some of the cases requires a Jordan Form and some do not because you can find two linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalues. For example:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = \lambda, v_1 = (0, 1), v_2 = (1, 0)$$

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \lambda_{1,2} = 0, v_1 = (1, 0), v_2 = (0,1)$$

The second example is a generalized eigenvector and this has a Jordan Form

$$A = PJP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The question was auto-deleted when the asker's user account was deleted, because the question had negative score. Further deletions of your answer are not to be expected unless the question gets closed.